# Lenovo w530 from 8.1 back to 7

Tags: windows-7, restore

I upgraded to 8.1 from 7, and then tried to go back to 7, restarted my laptop and hit F11 thinking I could get to the lenovo recovery tool. But it only takes me to windows 8.1 recovery options, none of which has restore factory settings. So I install windows 7 from a CD and did a clean install following steps from MS website. Now the laptop does recognize it's wireless adapter. I went and downloaded (from another machine) all possible drivers from Lenovo website, and it still does not work. Is there a place online I can download the image for factory settings for w530?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, if you are still under warranty, call up Lenovo support and they will send you all the original Windows 7 install disks for your computer. I did this, it works wonderfully.

Comment: Thanks i called them. I should get a call from a technician tomorrow. I just dont have much faith in this company so i thought I'll see if there is another route to explore.

Comment: http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/feedback/detail.page?LegacyDocID=MIGR-76613
Their 24 hour a day service number is here.
Do you still have the backup partition on the Thinkpad drive?
Typed from my Thinkpad.

Comment: Thanks T.C. i do have a Lenovo partition showing but not sure if it is usable. I configured the machine with a mini SSD for the OS. But i am not sure where is where. That us the number I called. Thanks again.

Comment: I called again and finally someone was able to put a request for a factory settings CD. Thank you all for the feedback. I hope it reaches quickly.